# Laravel pretty URL

Tags: laravel, pretty-urls

I'm going crazy here! I'm trying to learn Laravel and pretty URLs just don't work.

I have enabled `mod_rewrite` from my apache config file, I have set `AllowOverride` to `All` in my user config file and I have the following in my `.htaccess` file in `public` folder of Laravel installation:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I enter `http://localhost/~user/lara/public/index.php/users` it works, but with `http://localhost/~user/lara/public/users` I get `404 Not Found` error

```
The requested URL /Users/user/Sites/lara/public/index.php/users was not found on this server.
```

You can see that the redirection works fine, as `public/users` have turned into `public/index.php/users` but it says not found, even though when I manually enter `public/index.php/users` it show me the output.

I have read all the related questions on SO, none of the worked for me!

Comment: It may just be a typo in your question, but the URL that works for you is not in the `public` directory: `/~user/lara/index.php/users` as opposed to `/~user/lara/public/index.php/users` which is what your rewriterule would do for the `/~user/lara/public/users` URL.

Comment: it was a typo indeed, just corrected it

Comment: D'oh. Oh well, there go our hopes and dreams of a quick fix!

Comment: definitely :( I'm realy going crazy

Comment: It could be because the `~user` thing is using mod_userdir (or something similar), and so the rewrite rule isn't actually rewriting correctly (even if it looks like it is). try adding a RewriteBase in: `RewriteBase /~user/lara/public/` I'm aware it's not an elegant fix, but if it works, it works, right?

Comment: `RewriteBase /~user/lara/public/` solved the problem. but I didn't get what `mod_userdir` does, can you elaborate on that? thanks

Comment: Added an answer to explain the problem as I see it and promote the answer to your specific problem in case others come across the post and think it's unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the fact that you are changing the document root during a request. From the looks of your URL (with the `~user` segment) you are using `mod_userdir` or something similar, and what these types of plugins do it allow you to map a given URL prefix to a document root that is not the normal one for the server.

As such, you sometimes run into issues like this where the right .htaccess file is found, but its rewritten URL is against the original document root rather than the modified one and so your `index.php` file cannot be found (maybe, to be honest I don't really know, this is all conjecture). This is also why going directly to `index.php/users` works - the problem isn't the setup per se, but the mixing of rewrite rules and the change of the document root.

As such, the fix is to use a `RewriteBase` line, ad the following to the .htccess file:

```
RewriteBase /~user/lara/public/
```